# Winding number of a path inside a disk.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\mathbf{D}\subset\mathbb{C}$ be a disk such that $0\notin \mathbf{D}$ and $c:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ a path that is contained inside $\mathbf{D}$. I have to show that $W(c,0)$ the winding number of $c$ around $0$ is zero. I know that sounds kind of obvious but I actually have no idea how to prove it, I tried by showing that $W(c,0)=W(\Gamma,0)$ where $\Gamma$ is a parametrization of $\partial\mathbf{D}$ but, have had no success.

Comment: Geometrically it is trivial, and this should perhaps suffice as this is the usual intuition for the winding number's definition. Do you want to prove it with an integral? If the path is not closed then it is trivial (as it doesn't apply...), if the path is simple and closed also, and if it is closed *but* not simple then you can divide the integral in a finite number of integrals on simple closed paths, each of which is zero...

Comment: What is your definition of $W(c, z_0)$ for a closed curve $c$?

Comment: @ChristianBlatter $W(c,0)=1/2\pi i \int_{0}^{1}{c'(t)/c(t)dt}$.

Comment: @DonAntonio the path is closed but not necessarily simple.

Comment: @Monkey Great...yet it must have a finite number of cross points, so you can divide that path into a finite number of closed simple ones and apply the definition to each.

Comment: I see @DonAntonio thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$W(c,0)={1\over 2\pi i}\int_0^1{c'(t)\over c(t)}\>dt={1\over 2\pi i}\int_c{1\over z}\>dz\ .$$
Since the origin is outside your domain $D$ the function $z\mapsto {1\over z}$ is analytic in $D$. Therefore by Cauchy's theorem the integral on the right hand side is $=0$.